# Converting a datframe into a list of column retaining the column names -python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
a    b
---------
1   xyz
2   pqr
3   mno
```

I need to convert into something like

```
(a=[1,2,3],b=[xyz,pqr,mno])
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that's a bad way of organising your data.

One better way you could do is convert dataframe into a dictionary where keys are column names and values are column values as a list. Something like this:

```
df.to_dict('list')  # df is your Dataframe.
```

This outputs:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['xyz', 'pqr', 'mno']}
```

Now you could access columns individually pretty easily.

```
dct.get('a')   # -> [1, 2, 3] where dct is the dictionary obtained above.
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas Transpose,

```
>>> import pandas as pd    

>>> data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ab', 'bc', 'ca']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   A   B
0  1  ab
1  2  bc
2  3  ca
>>> df.T
    0   1   2
A   1   2   3
B  ab  bc  ca
>>> list(df.loc['A'])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(df.loc['B'])
['ab', 'bc', 'ca']
>>> b = list(df.loc['B'])
>>> b
['ab', 'bc', 'ca']
```